# Entity Framework databind through loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am new in EF.when we work with datareader or dataset then sometime we populate control's value in a loop. like

```
  datareader dr=getdata()
  while(dr.read())
  {
    // in this loop we can populate control with value from datareader 
  }

  dataset ds =getdata()
  for(int i=0;i<=ds.tables[0].rows.count-1;i++)
  {
    // in this loop we can populate control with value from dataset
  }
```

so i just want to know when i work with EF then how can i iterate in loop and populate controls with value.

another question is how to chek null in EF.

please help me with sample code to understand the things. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a contrived code example to show how you might achieve what you require.

```
// Get all the cars
List<Car> cars = context.Cars.ToList();

// Clear the DataViewGrid
uiGrid.Rows.Clear();

// Populate the grid
foreach (Car car in cars)
{
    // Add a new row
    int rowIndex = uiGrid.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewRow newRow = uiGrid.Rows[rowIndex];

    // Populate the cells with data for this car
    newRow.Cells["Make"].Value = car.Make;
    newRow.Cells["Model"].Value = car.Model;
    newRow.Cells["Description"].Value = car.Description;

    // If the price is not null then add it to the price column
    if (car.Price != null)
    {
        newRow.Cells["Price"].Value = car.Price;
    }
    else
    {
        newRow.Cells["Price"].Value = "No Price Available";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help:

http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/a-quick-guide-to-using-entity-framework